# Trigger canvas animation on hover

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have canvas/javascript animation. How do I trigger traces on hover of the logo element?

```
setInterval(function() {
   traces = !traces
}, 5000)
```

Link https://codepen.io/NGrdanjski/pen/XKkwAY

Comment: Corrected the question.

Answer (score 2):

An event listener on the canvas will do this for you.

https://codepen.io/mrkiefer/pen/wWmEJb

I removed the setInterval that toggles the traces variable, and instead, added:

```
cvs.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
           traces = true;
        });

 cvs.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            traces = false;
        });
```

If you want to turn the trades on only when the mouse is over the logo, then you would add the mouse listeners to the logo div instead:

https://codepen.io/mrkiefer/pen/KroGJo

```
    logo = document.getElementById("logo");


     logo.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
           traces = true;
        });

 logo.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            traces = false;
        });
```

Here, when you put the mouse over the stackoverflow logo, the star traces are turned on.

Comment: Thank you.
I need to set trace = true only when i hover over logo div (#logo), and set traces = false when i mouse out. If we understand.

Comment: It was tough getting the logo on the screen. When you re-added the element to the end of the document, this covered up the logo for good. My edits now include only mousing over the logo.

Comment: Matthew, **Please do not use external script runners (eg codepen) for your demos.** Your links can rot or the websites can be offline.  Stackoverflow has built-in [Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) you can use for demos.